# Json from url - array in array

Tags: python, arrays, json

I want take data from API from polish http by json format. But, I have problem take data from array in array.
From "normal" json I can took data, but this json have struture as 'krs_podmioty.id' => 'blabla' <= I have problem with . (dot) and array in array.

I try get data from https://api-v3.mojepanstwo.pl/dane/krs_podmioty/10186.json?layers[]=dzialalnosci&layers[]=reprezentacja.
You can decode on: http://freeonlinetools24.com/json-decode (and past text from http).
It's public website and data.

If you will look it, I want data from segment:

'krs_podmioty'.person_id' =>  array ( 0 => '14439' .... 11 => '1233301' )

```
import urllib.request
import json

res = urllib.request.urlopen('https://api-v3.mojepanstwo.pl/dane/krs_podmioty/10186.json?layers[]=dzialalnosci&layers[]=reprezentacja')
res_body = res.read()

j = json.loads(res_body.decode("utf-8"))

for item in j['data']:
    ucmdbId = (item['krs_podmioty'])
    print('Id podmioty: '.format(ucmdbId))

exit(0)
```

In perfect situation I need print list of all "krs_podmioty.person_id"

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import requests
import json 

result = requests.get('https://api-v3.mojepanstwo.pl/dane/krs_podmioty/10186.json?layers[]=dzialalnosci&layers[]=reprezentacja').json()
ids = result['data']['krs_podmioty.person_id']
for id in ids:
    print('Id podmioty: ' + id)
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
   for item in j['data']['krs_podmioty.person_id']:
        ucmdbId = item
        print('Id podmioty: {0} '.format(ucmdbId))
```

`j['data']` contained all of the objects in the `'data'` array in which you could call for the `krs_podmioty.person_id` key to get its corresponding value array.